# Track everything with git-lfs

Tags: git-lfs

I was wondering, why does no one use git with LFS to track everything? Since we configure LFS to track files based on the file extension instead of file size, I was thinking about tracking all my project files. Did anyone try this approach yet? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git LFS is mainly useful for binary files where regular [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) doesn't make sense. This means that whenever you push a change in Git LFS, the whole file will be reuploaded instead of Git being smart about it and only uploading the lines where there is a change.

Also worth noting is that Github charges by both LFS repo size and used bandwidth.